# How to Implement AR Wall Measurement Functionality in Flutter App for Android? Point A to point B

Tags: android, flutter, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm developing a Flutter app that utilizes augmented reality (AR) to measure walls, from point A to point B. Currently, we've successfully implemented this feature on iOS. However, we're facing difficulties implementing it on Android. It seems that the AR package available for Android is primarily designed for positioning 3D objects in the virtual plane. How can we implement wall measurement functionality in Flutter for Android devices? Any insights or alternative packages would be greatly appreciated.

i have tried the arcore package